# how to make table width fit to width of column?

Tags: tables, two-column

This table should fit into one column of two column page perfectly. But it displayed a bit longer than column width. I want to make it fit correctly.

```
    \begin{table}[h] 
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3} 
    \caption{example}
    \label{an example}
    \centering 
    \hrule
    \begin{align*}
     &(\lambda x.xx)\lambda m \lambda n. m n &\\
     &(xx)[x:=\underline{\lambda m \lambda n. m n}] &\textbf{Step 2}  \\
     &(\underline{\lambda m_1 \lambda n_1. m_1 n_1})(\underline{\lambda m_2    \lambda n_2. m_2 n_2}) \\
     &(\lambda n_1. m_1 n_1)[m_1:=\lambda m_2 \lambda n_2. m_2 n_2] \\
     & \lambda n_1.((m_1 n_1)[m_1:=\underline{\lambda m_2 \lambda n_2. m_2 n_2}])   &\textbf{Step 5} \\
     & \lambda n_1.((m_1[m_1:=\underline{\lambda m_3 \lambda n_3. m_3 n_3}])(n_1[m_1:=\underline{\lambda m_4 \lambda n_4. m_4 n_4}]))  \\
     & \lambda n_1.((\lambda m_3 \lambda n_3. m_3 n_3)n_1)\\
     & \lambda n_1.((\lambda n_3. m_3 n_3)[m_3:=n_1]) \\
     & \lambda n_1.(\lambda n_3. ((m_3 n_3)[m_3:=\underline{n_1}])) &\textbf{Step 9} \\
    & \lambda n_1.(\lambda n_3.((m_3[m_3:=\underline{n_1}])(n_3[m_3:=\underline{n_1}]))) \\
    & \lambda n_1.(\lambda n_3.(n_1 n_3))
    \end{align*}
    \normalsize
    \hrule
    \end{table}
```

There is a image shows my problem, the width is little bit bigger than it should be. (did not show the left column completely, but I think you can see)

[image]

how can I do that? thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you use.

Comment: The way align works, every line has to have room for the "Step" column, even if they don't use it.  You could use \tag{\textbf{Step 2}} for example instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, that you use standard article class, you can fit your set of equations in one column width if you broke the longest equation into two line:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

    \begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
    \begin{table}[h]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \caption{example}
    \label{an example}
    \centering
    \hrule
    \begin{align*}
     &(\lambda x.xx)\lambda m \lambda n. m n &\\
     &(xx)[x:=\underline{\lambda m \lambda n. m n}] 
        &   \textbf{Step 1}  \\
     &(\underline{\lambda m_1 \lambda n_1. m_1 n_1})(\underline{\lambda m_2    \lambda n_2. m_2 n_2}) \\
     &(\lambda n_1. m_1 n_1)[m_1:=\lambda m_2 \lambda n_2. m_2 n_2] \\
     & \lambda n_1.((m_1 n_1)[m_1:=\underline{\lambda m_2 \lambda n_2. m_2 n_2}])
            & \textbf{Step 5} \\
     & \begin{multlined}[0.5\linewidth]
        \lambda n_1.((m_1[m_1 :=\underline{\lambda m_3 \lambda n_3. m_3 n_3}])\\
            (n_1[m_1 :=\underline{\lambda m_4 \lambda n_4. m_4 n_4}]))  
        \end{multlined} \\
     & \lambda n_1.((\lambda m_3 \lambda n_3. m_3 n_3)n_1)\\
     & \lambda n_1.((\lambda n_3. m_3 n_3)[m_3:=n_1]) \\
     & \lambda n_1.(\lambda n_3. ((m_3 n_3)[m_3:=\underline{n_1}])) 
                &   \textbf{Step 9} \\
    & \lambda n_1.(\lambda n_3.((m_3[m_3:=\underline{n_1}])(n_3[m_3:=\underline{n_1}]))) \\
    & \lambda n_1.(\lambda n_3.(n_1 n_3))
    \end{align*}
    \normalsize
    \hrule
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** solution with all equations in one line and still have `\footnotesize` fonts. By help  of `tabular` environment is possible to allow to the longest equation to protrude in space column with comments about steps:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}

    \begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
    \begin{table}[h]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \footnotesize
    \caption{example}
    \label{an example}
    \centering
    \hrule
    \begin{tabular}{@{} >{$}p{0.82\linewidth}<{$} >{\bfseries}l @{}}
(\lambda x.xx)\lambda m \lambda n. m n              &           \\
(xx)[x:=\underline{\lambda m \lambda n. m n}]       &   Step 2  \\
(\underline{\lambda m_1 \lambda n_1. m_1 n_1})
(\underline{\lambda m_2\lambda n_2. m_2 n_2})       &           \\
(\lambda n_1. m_1 n_1)[m_1:=\lambda m_2 \lambda n_2. m_2 n_2]   
                                                    &           \\
\lambda n_1.((m_1 n_1)[m_1:=\underline{\lambda m_2 \lambda n_2. m_2 n_2}])
                                                    &   Step 5  \\
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{$
\lambda n_1.((m_1[m_1 :=\underline{\lambda m_3 \lambda n_3. m_3 n_3}])
            (n_1[m_1 :=\underline{\lambda m_4 \lambda n_4. m_4 n_4}]))
                      $}                                        \\
\lambda n_1.((\lambda m_3 \lambda n_3. m_3 n_3)n_1) &           \\
\lambda n_1.((\lambda n_3. m_3 n_3)[m_3:=n_1])      &           \\
\lambda n_1.(\lambda n_3. ((m_3 n_3)[m_3:=\underline{n_1}]))
                                                    &   Step 9  \\
\lambda n_1.(\lambda n_3.((m_3[m_3:=\underline{n_1}])
            (n_3[m_3:=\underline{n_1}])))           &           \\
\lambda n_1.(\lambda n_3.(n_1 n_3))                 &
    \end{tabular}
    \normalsize
    \hrule
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I updated it with a picture. I think I don't have to break long lines because it is still shorter than column width,  as shown in picture.

Answer (score 1):

If you can fit the longest equation into the column, then this will work.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[h] 
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3} 
    \caption{example}
    \label{an example}
    \centering 
    \rule{\columnwidth}{.5pt}
    \begin{align*}
     &(\lambda x.xx)\lambda m \lambda n. m n &\\
     &(xx)[x:=\underline{\lambda m \lambda n. m n}] \tag{\textbf{Step 2}}  \\
     &(\underline{\lambda m_1 \lambda n_1. m_1 n_1})(\underline{\lambda m_2    \lambda n_2. m_2 n_2}) \\
     &(\lambda n_1. m_1 n_1)[m_1:=\lambda m_2 \lambda n_2. m_2 n_2] \\
     & \lambda n_1.((m_1 n_1)[m_1:=\underline{\lambda m_2 \lambda n_2. m_2 n_2}])   \tag{\textbf{Step 5}} \\
     & \lambda n_1.((m_1[m_1:=\underline{\lambda m_3 \lambda n_3. m_3 n_3}])
       (n_1[m_1:=\underline{\lambda m_4 \lambda n_4. m_4 n_4}]))  \\
     & \lambda n_1.((\lambda m_3 \lambda n_3. m_3 n_3)n_1)\\
     & \lambda n_1.((\lambda n_3. m_3 n_3)[m_3:=n_1]) \\
     & \lambda n_1.(\lambda n_3. ((m_3 n_3)[m_3:=\underline{n_1}])) \tag{\textbf{Step 9}} \\
    & \lambda n_1.(\lambda n_3.((m_3[m_3:=\underline{n_1}])(n_3[m_3:=\underline{n_1}]))) \\
    & \lambda n_1.(\lambda n_3.(n_1 n_3))
    \end{align*}
    \normalsize
    \hrule
    \end{table} 

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]